# Assign texture to TModel3D

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have a [TModel3D](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Objects3D.TModel3D) that I can get to show up inside a viewport3d, but I cannot figure out how to texture it...

```
procedure TForm2.createMap(r:integer;c:integer);
var
    player : tmodel3d;

begin
    player := TModel3d.Create(self);
    player.Visible := true;
    Player.Position.X := 0;
    player.Position.Y := 0;
    player.position.Z := 2;
    player.LoadFromFile(gamedir + '\pics\player.dae');
    player.Parent := viewport3d1;
```

I have tried all I can think of, but how do make "texture.jpg" texture the model?

When I run this I do see the model without texture.

Comment: added   `player.MeshCollection[0].Material.texture.loadfromfile(gamedir+'\pics\playertexture.bmp');`  after the player loadfromfile.. now it gives access errors any idea?

Comment: I think that your major flaw is actually trying to do something productive in Delphi XE2 - FMX 0.00001 Pre-pre-Alpha.

Comment: i use what I am givin...

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I just wanted to warn you about the obvious pitfalls that come with using XE2 Firemonkey. There is a high chance for when you decide to update Delphi that you will have to completely rewrite your FMX applications which will make your current attempt to resolve FMX 1 issues a complete time waste.

Comment: @PeterVonča That seems to be the case in every update :D.  I am trying to get an xe3 or even 4  but its all up to my school, and if they can get student versions..

Comment: I don't have XE2, but I can confirm Textures load correctly with XE4  from a DAE model. have you verified path of the textures in the DAE file ? the path should be relative to the model file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested contextually on XE2 here with my own DAE model and texture file, and seems to work well.

```
procedure TForm2.createMap(r:integer;c:integer);
var
 player :  tmodel3d;

begin
 // NEVER create a 3D object as a sub-component of anything other than a 3D viewport!
 player := TModel3d.Create(viewport3d1);
 {
   Ensure that the Parent is always set before operating on the control.
   Some operations (such as texturing) will force the object to be re-rendered
   so if your parent isn't specified (or isn't ready for rendering) it will cause
   some nasty bugs.
 }
 player.Parent := viewport3d1;
 player.Visible := true;
 Player.Position.X := 0;
 player.Position.Y := 0;
 player.position.Z := 2;
 player.LoadFromFile(gamedir+'\pics\player.dae');
 player.MeshCollection[0].Material.texture.loadfromfile(gamedir+'\pics\playertex‌​ture.bmp');
```

From a game architecture perspective, you should really create a custom class akin to `TPlayer`, and have the model as a member of that object. This way, all player controls can be associated with `TPlayer`, and it becomes a described entity as opposed to just a model you have to manually manipulate from higher up in your game logic.

Also you want to ensure that the position of your model and that of your camera are such that it's within the camera's perspective frame.

Comment: ok so i have exactly like you do but no model ever shows up and i get access error on the player.meshcollection[0]....  I know i have the position correct cause when i add a TModel3d i use the same x,y,z as i have here and it will show up.. Can you see any other reason?

Comment: Update, when using loadfromfile you must add fmx.obj.importer or fmx.dae.Importer   now model shows but still no texture..also no errors , it just dont show up  take a look 
http://img42.com/mzMCs

Comment: The code posted will work but fmx seems to only like 1 of the 6 models I tried. So more of how to get right file spec is the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 10

```
   For I := 0 to Length(Model3d1.MeshCollection) - 1 do
      Model3d1.MeshCollection[I].MaterialSource := TextureMaterialSource1;
```